# Problem getting Oauth to work with Ecobee

Tags: authentication

I am trying to get the Oauth to work with ecobee thermostat. I could get to the point where I get the user to the Oauth page, however, on clicking the "Accept" button, it takes me to https://www.ecobee.com/en-us/ instead of taking me to the redirect uri.

The redirect uri is not available on the internet yet and is something I redirected to my localhost using hosts file, but this shouldn't matter. My browser window should be taking me to the redirect uri.

Anyone who has worked with ecobee thermostat have any idea?

Comment: any update on this? I am facing same issue.